# Anbox not working for me

Tags: anbox

I installed Anbox a couple of days ago and it worked wonderfully. I was able to install the Google Play Store and then install Microsoft Word, and was able to use Word on Linux!

Since yesterday, I have been experiencing this issue where Anbox hangs on starting for about half a minute, and then crashes. Attempting to run Anbox from the command line gave the following:

```
[ 2018-10-12 05:50:27] [launch.cpp:182@operator()] Session manager is not yet running, trying to start it
[ 2018-10-12 05:50:27] [launch.cpp:116@launch_session_manager] Started session manager, will now try to connect ..
[ 2018-10-12 05:50:27] [splash_screen.cpp:50@SplashScreen] Window has no associated renderer yet, creating one ...
[ 2018-10-12 05:50:32] [daemon.cpp:61@Run] Failed to retrieve ready property from application manager
```

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Can someone please help me out with this? I can't bear this error. I've tried refreshing the snap package, but still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run this command before

```
anbox session-manager
```